# MacVim does not pick up global mappings from plugins?

Tags: macvim

I'm trying to figure out why MacVim does not pick up global mappings from installed plugins. I am using MacVim 7.3.87 under OS X 10.6.

I created a file ~/.vim/plugin/testplugin.vim containing the following:

```
nmap <D-x> :echo "hello"<cr>
nmap <C-x> :echo "hello"<cr>
nmap ,x :echo "hello"<cr>
```

Then I started MacVim using "mvim -V2" and verified by checking debug messages that testplugin.vim was sourced. Once it was up and running, I used the :nmap command to see all the normal-mode mappings but didn't see any mappings from testplugin.vim. Of course, those mappings do not work.

I noticed that the text-mode vim from MacPorts does pick up global mappings from this same testplugin.vim, so I'm wondering if MacVim specifically disables plugin global mappings.

Comment: Maybe contact some the macvim developer? http://code.google.com/p/macvim/people/list

Comment: Here is his blog: http://b4winckler.wordpress.com/

Comment: He suggested to try the troubleshooting steps here: https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/Troubleshooting  I'll do that on Monday.

Answer (score 2):

I used the [troubleshooting steps](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/Troubleshooting) and figured out the problem.  Thanks to Björn Winckler for the offsite advice.  It turned out to be a conflict in the order in which config files were sourced.  After the plugins were loaded, another file came in with "mapclear" and removed all the mappings.